# mySQL INSERT запрос в Java

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, запрос

Есть вот такая конструкция

```
String query = "INSERT INTO database.postinfo (post_id) \n" +
                    " VALUES ('id' );";
try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);

} catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
    sqlEx.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    //close connection and stmt heare
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }
    try {
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) { /*can't do anything */ }

}
```

Я хочу чтобы в VALUES передавались значения полученных переменных. Например у меня есть переменная полученная с помощью Jsoup, и я хочу передать ее в VALUES для заполнения столбца post_id, но в моем примере выше передается только текст 'id'(дословно), а не значение переменной.

```
id = doc.select("div.story").attr("data-story-id")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно использовать prepared statement. Для этого в sql-запросе заменяете все внешние параметры на знаки вопроса, а затем для каждого из параметров задаёте значение с помощью методов `stmt.set...`. Нумерация параметров начинается с единицы.
Например:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO database.postinfo (post_id, some_int) VALUES (?, ?)";
//...
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "your-id"); // 1 - порядковый номер параметра ("?") внутри запроса
stmt.setInt(2, 456);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

где `"your-id"` и `456` надо заменить на нужные значения. При таком подходе не будет ошибок из-за спецсимволов в передаваемых параметрах.

Comment: т.е. для каждого параметра нужно писать отдельный PreparedStatement?

Comment: @РоманDriveMind Нет, в одном запросе может быть несколько параметров. Давайте я дополню пример.

Comment: Все, я понял. спасибо